# Oesterlé's unpublished bound on Uniform Boundedness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

The bound in Merel's solution to the Uniform Boundedness conjecture is not explicit, as it relies on Falting's work on the Mordell conjecture. I think this still is the case.

But there are known explicit bounds for the largest prime divisor. The best one seems to be $(1+3^{d/2})^2$, where $d$ is the degree of the number field, due de Oesterlé (1994!). But as far as I known, the proof of such a bound remains unpublished.

Quoting a relatively recent survey on the topic for context ("Torsion subgroups of elliptic curves over number fields" by Andrew Sutherland, 2012):

> *Oesterlé's bound plays a critical role in several of the results
>   discussed here; it is quite unfortunate that no proof has been
>   published. The work of Parent in implies that Oesterlé's bound holds
>   for all suffciently large d, but we are typically interested in
>   particular small values of d (e.g. d = 5; 6; 7). **There is current work
>   in progress aimed at addressing this gap in the literature** [6]*.
>
> *[6] Maarten Derickx, e-mail regarding innitely many rational points
>   on a modular curve of degree Q-gonality 2, December 2012.*

- My question is, has this gap been filled? Alternatively, has Oesterlé's work been superseded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is published as appendix A to chapter 3 in Derickx' PhD thesis available here: https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/handle/1887/43186 . The thesis contains, of course, many more interesting results.

Comment: 1-step link: https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/43186/03.pdf . It looks like a preprint: *M. Derickx, S. Kamieny, W. Stein, M. Stoll. Torsion points on elliptic curves over number fields of small degree.* If once there's a reference it could be added here.